# django media hook not picking up the right directory

Tags: python, django

I have setup the following in my urls.py:

```
 (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT})
```

and my settings are:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'd:/~Sasha/Portman/media/'
MEDIA_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/media/'
```

and the following url:

```
http://localhost:8000/media/icons/151.png
```

returns:

```
"d:\install\python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\media\icons\151.png" does not exist
```

is there something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that settings.ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX and MEDIA_ROOT were pointing to the same /media/ ending so r'^media/' was mixing them. Changed ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX to /admin-media/ and it all works now.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a project directory setting in settings.py that other settings use.

My setup:

```
BASE_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
...
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_PATH, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static').replace('\\', '/'),
    os.path.join(BASE_PATH, 'static'),
)
```

and then in urls.py, at the end

```
if settings.DEBUG:
  urlpatterns += patterns("",
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',      {'document_root':settings.MEDIA_ROOT})
)
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. The settings are surely found by the app - say the db settings are happily retrieved. Is it the BASE_PATH you are saying I'm missing? The funny thing is that the other application that uses the same /media/ settings is happily working without the BASE_PATH :)

Comment: do you have those lines in urls.py? are you running with DEBUG True or False?